# Update HashMap/ArrayList passed to PriorityQueue Comparator

Tags: java, hashmap, priority-queue, comparator

I wrote a comparator for a PriorityQueue so that it will give me the smallest value based on the first value in the ArrayList from the HashMap.

My issue is that, in the rest of my program I need to update/change those first values in the ArrayList. I'm not sure how to do that to make sure the priority queue always gives me the proper result based on the updates?

Thanks

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer>{
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> hm;
    public MyComparator(HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> hm){
        this.hm = hm;
    }
    @Override
    public int compare (Integer num, Integer num1){
        ArrayList<Integer> list = hm.get(num);
        int w = list.get(0);
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = hm.get(num1);
        int w1 = list1.get(0);
        if(w1 - w == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        if(w1 - w <= 0){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will give you the proper result at the time you call compare method. also, just to mention it shouldn't be `if(w1 - w < 0){ return 1;}` ?

Comment: So the compare method is called each time I do PriorityQueue.peek(); ? Thus using the updated hash map/array lists? And yeah thanks for pointing that out... the '=' shouldn't be there

Answer (score 0):

If you change the value that you're using as a key in a `PriorityQueue`, you need to adjust the queue to reflect the change. Otherwise, your queue will potentially be in an invalid state. The data structure can't keep track of changes you make to whatever value you're using as a key. If you change the keys, you have to notify the data structure that things changed.

The queue pointedly *will not* re-organize itself whenever you call `peek`. All `peek` does is return the first item in the queue. The only comparison it makes is to see if the queue is empty.

The only way to re-organize a Java `PriorityQueue` is to remove the element that you changed, and then re-insert it.